# copy multiple files based on partial filename in python

Tags: python, copy

I'm trying to copy specific files from my web-folder to another directory based on list.

In my web-folder :

```
Class_01_Stu20230101.txt
Class_02_Stu20230102.txt
Class_03_Tea20230101.txt
Class_04_Tea20230103.txt
Class_05_20230101_20230107.txt
Class_06_EST22758624_EST22758668.txt
Class_2042_Stu20230104.txt
Class_2043_Stu20230104.txt
...
```

I want to copy specific files by list which consists of partial filename.

lists will like that:

```
lt= [*range(01,03), *range(2178,2186), *range(5020,5024)]
lists= [f"Class_{i}_*.txt" for i in lt]
```

And I have tried this:

```
import os, shutil

path= 'G:/source/path/dir'
new_path= 'D:/test'
files= os.listdir(path)
lt= [*range(01,03), *range(2178,2186), *range(5020,5024)]
lists= [f"Class_{i}_*.txt" for i in lt]

for file in files:
    for list in lists:
        if list in file:
            print(file) #printing goes just fine
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, file), new_path)
```

But got empty.Any help on this? Thank you.

Comment: Use `glob.glob()` to expand wildcards.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for advice.but I dont understand where should I edit ..

Answer (score 0):

Obvious you intend to filter files by something like regex (I see wildcards here). I would write a function `get_files_by_regex(path, regex)`. With that I would build up one ordered list and iterate over those one calling the function providing you the list of files to copy. For regex see documentation of the `re` module.

A few notes in addition:

- `lists` is not a good variable name (keyword in Python)
- `if lists in file` -> you meant `if file in lists` but in this cases you don't match since file is a concrete one but your lists do have wilcard entries.

Comment: `lists` isn't a built-in, `list` is.